# Copypasting page of my vue/cli 4 app into browser I got invalid page

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I found that is to copypaste page of my vue/cli 4 app into browser, it opens invalid page, ex:
http://my-site.com/events
But if to open home page 
http://my-site.com
and move to events by clicking on menu then page with http://my-site.com/events url is opened ok.

In my src/router/index.js I have defined :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

and in process.env.BASE_URL is default...

Is it possible to open http://my-site.com/events by coipypasting url ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "teach" your server that any request to `http://my-site.com/*` (* can be anything) should be served by your `index.html`

See the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)